# os.system command not found after string formatting

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to pass a variable inside an os.system command however i get an error message "command not found" after the string formatting mark. It seems that it tries to execute the text right after the string formatting as command.

```py
import os

BOOT_VOLUME_ATTACHMENT_ID = os.popen("terraform output | grep volume_attachment_id | cut -d ' ' -f 3").read()

os.system('oci compute boot-volume-attachment detach --force  --wait-for-state DETACHED --boot-volume-attachment-id {0} --region region1' .format(BOOT_VOLUME_ATTACHMENT_ID))
```

The result is the error bellow:

```
sh: line 1: --region: command not found
```

Why is python trying to execute the string right after the string formatting as a command?

**I am using Python2.7**

**UPDATE** .

It seems that the problem is in the variable `BOOT_VOLUME_ATTACHMENT_ID` . If i change this variable to a manual string , say "123" it works fine. However if i use os.popen then i see the mentioned error

Comment: Are you sure --region is a valid option?

Comment: @JammyDodger Why shouldn't it? After all, it is `sh` complaining about it as a command.

Comment: @JammyDodger is i am sure, if a swapp the text with something else, lets say "boot-volume-attachment" it will error with command not found "boot-volume-attachment" :/

Comment: Looks like you have an extra space between your sting and format statement, may just be a typo here but could also cause your issue

Comment: @Joe just tried it , same error :-(

Comment: Does the command work directly, without python

Comment: @Joe yes that's the weird thing, directly it works fine, Everything i place right after the string formatting mark it will be executed as a command. Its like it ignores all text before the {} mark.

Comment: Maybe try creating the full string before passing it to `os.system`. Then pass the full string as a single variable.  This way there is less chance of the format method messing it up

Comment: @Joe The chance is the same, but doing it the way you suggest, it can better be debugged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from `os.system` being by way inferior to `subprocess`, the likely problem is the substitution process done by `.format()`.

Instead of your code, you should try

```py
BOOT_VOLUME_ATTACHMENT_ID = "123"
print(repr('oci compute boot-volume-attachment detach --force  --wait-for-state DETACHED --boot-volume-attachment-id {0} --region region1'.format(BOOT_VOLUME_ATTACHMENT_ID)))
```

and look what it outputs.

This will tell you if there is something strange (e. g. a line break) before the `--region`.

After your question update, it becomes clear that your `BOOT_VOLUME_ATTACHMENT_ID` isn't what you claimed it to be. Instead, it contains the output of a different program, which in most cases adds a line break at the end.

If you take that content and plug it into a string the way you did, this line break gets transferred into the destination string, telling the shell to execute two commands.

The solution is to use `.strip()` immediately after the `os.popen()` call.

---

About subprocess:

Your program will become cleaner (e. g. less injection-prone) if you do

```py
import subprocess
BOOT_VOLUME_ATTACHMENT_ID = "123"
subprocess.call(['oci', 'compute', 'boot-volume-attachment', 'detach', '--force', '--wait-for-state', 'DETACHED', '--boot-volume-attachment-id', BOOT_VOLUME_ATTACHMENT_ID, '--region', 'region1'])
```

The reason is that this avoids having the shell between your program and `oci`, thus eliminating one potential source of errors.

Comment: There actually are 3 parentheses at the end, you've missed one.

Comment: The output prints the command which looks ok. I even copy-pasted the command and works fine. But when it is run in python it fails with the same error. I will try the subprocess see what happens.

Comment: What does it print?

Comment: @glglgl yup ... you were right mate.. the os.peopen will add a `\n`  which caused the error. I was able to see it with the "print(repr"